Google dependency issue when using Youtube library
I'm getting:

You are currently running with version 2.5.1 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version 1.25.0 of the YouTube Data API library.

When I try to use the youtube.videos.insert provided by the google-api-services-youtube dependency.
To my knowledge I'm using the most up to date version of google-api-client and youtube dependency, what is the right way forward?
Reverting to google-api-client version 1.35.2 works, though I wonder if there is a better solution
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.36.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.44.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev222-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>

